# Android Row becomes Unclickable with Button

Tags: java, android

I have a listView, where each row has a button in the row layout. However, this seems to make the row itself unclickable. How can I make both the button and row clickable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to set itemsCanFocus on the list like this:

```
    mList.setItemsCanFocus(true);
```

To make the button clickable. Then you will need to use your own adapter and in getView return a view which is Clickable and focusable. You will also lose the default highlight states so you need to put them back in with the background resource. So do this:

```
    view.setClickable(true);
    view.setFocusable(true);
    view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.menuitem_background);
```

to your view before returning your view.

Comment: Thank you very much. In addition I had to add an OnClickListener to the view.

Comment: Any idea how to get the highlight states of the holo themes that is used in lists by default? `menuitem_background` is orange but the default state should be blueish.

Comment: This doesn't work. The AdapterView.OnItemClickListener is never called.

Comment: I have the same question as @rndstr! Any help?

Comment: To do it all in **xml**, see [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9841730/2350083)

Answer (score 9):

Whenever I see posts concerning the `android:focusable` and `android:clickable` attributes, I always see them being both set to the same value at once. I figured there must be a reason if they are two separate attributes instead of being one.

It turns out that a much better way of achieving your desired behavior is to set

```
android:focusable="false"
```

or

```
yourButton.setFocusable(false)
```

on the `Button` in your `View`. Once you do that, you'll be both able to set an `OnClickListener` on the `Button`, and a click on the row will fire the `onListItemClick()` method in your `OnItemClickListener`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set your widgets to **non clickable and non focusable** in xml,the click on items will work normally and also the click on button will work normally.

```
android:clickable="false" 
android:focusable="false"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think that is possible.  You ListView row can either have focusable widgets, like a button, *or* be clickable, not both.  See [link.](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/1fde30269b97f998/8f982b5c68febcf5)