# Can't click on ListView row with imagebutton

Tags: android, listview, imagebutton

I have trouble with a `ListView`. Its items (rows) have an `ImageButton`.
The `ImageButton` has `android:onClick` set, so this `onClick` event is working, but click on row doesn't work.

If I remove the `ImageButton` from the row item, click on row works (`ListView` has correct `onClick` listener). How can I fix it?
I need `onClick` event when the user clicks on the `ImageButton`, and the standard click event when the user selects the row (not click the `ImageButton` but click the row).

My ListView:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/restaurants_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:divider="@color/list_devider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="@color/list_background" />
```

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Unfortunately,

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

doesn't work for `ImageButton`.

I finally found the solution [here](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2011/08/focus-problems-with-list-rows-and.html). In your layout xml for those items, add

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to the root view.

It works perfectly for a `ListView` that has `ImageButton`s. According to [official reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:descendantFocusability), `blocksDescendants` means that the `ViewGroup` will block its descendants from receiving focus.

Comment: For `ToggleButton` the `android:focusable="false"` is enough but for an ImageButton only `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` will work.

Comment: I added this code to my list item's root view and it works! I can both click on the listview and the ImageButton without any problem. Thanks

Comment: just to clarify: the `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` should be placed in the root viewgroup of the list-item layout

Answer (score 7):

You can use a custom adapter for your listView (if you haven't already). And there, in the `getView(int position, View inView, ViewGroup parent)` method of the adapter do something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View inView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = inView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder; //Use a viewholder for sufficent use of the listview

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) adaptersContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
        v.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

        .....

    viewHolder.image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Click on imageView
        }i
    });

    v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Click on listView row
        }
    });

        .....

    return (v);
}
```

See [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) if you need help creating your custom adapter.

Comment: Be aware that this solution prevents the row itself from being selected. In certain cases, you may want a listview where you can select a row AND click on a button within a row.

Comment: Is it desirable to make a new listener for every requested view?

Comment: @Maarten If by desirable you mean efficient,then it is efficient since using the `ViewHolder` technique, the `ListView` will store in memmory only the rows needed and not all the rows.

Comment: And it will create a new object for every row requested -- the reason why Views are recycled in the first place. If you go for performance, you should create a getOnClickListener(View) method and change the recycled listener around in getView(), not create a new one every time.

Comment: @Maarten Yes you are right. But i do not think you will gain any significant performance advantage since when the `View` of a row will be destroyed, the Garbage Collector will destroy the `OnClickListener` objects of that `View` since only that particular `View` has a reference to them.

Comment: But say you have a list of 10.000 items and you scroll through it fast. All these click listeners get instantiated and destroyed again (because there's no more reference to them), surely that would give a noticeable performance lag?

Comment: @Maarten You can create a sample project to test it. I think you are probably right but i have not tested to give you a definite answer. My code sample was just to show the user how he can make clickable `Views` inside the row of a `ListView` so i was not focusing on performance.

Answer (score 6):

If a row of listView have any clickable element like `Button` , `Image`..etc..then `onItemClick` will not work. So you need to write the click listener in `getView` of your list adapter.

For more read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2369327/1436931).

Answer (score 2):

Set these properties for your button:

```
      android:focusable="false"
      android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Or you can set it dynamically in your adapter class:

```
        yourButton.setFocusable(false);
    yourButton.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

And make sure that you set the choice mode as single for the listview:

```
       listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Comment: It worked for me, why do you say that it haven't work? I have a row with a checkbox, another stuff and the button. The row can be selected, and the button and the checkbox too.

Comment: However, it is really weird that android:focusable="false" doesn't work for ImageButton.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` for main layer did not work, neither in the ListView. I also tried `android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` which I heard that it is working for Buttons, but I had ImageButton so it didn't.

But setting the properties of the button in the CS file of the Layout worked.

```
var imageButton = view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.imageButton1);
imageButton.Focusable = false;
imageButton.FocusableInTouchMode = false;
imageButton.Clickable = true;
```

Comment: I'm using my own ImageButton. non of other answers worked for me, but this works. (I used them in my Custom Adapter)

Answer (score 1):

If a row has multiple clickable elements, onItemClick() will not work. You will need to set the `OnClickListener` in the `getView()` method. Store the listeners the the View's tag so that they can be recycled, add methods to your listeners so they can be specialized for different rows.

```
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        RowClickListeners listeners = (RowClickListeners) view.getTag();
        if (listeners == null) {
            listeners = new RowClickListeners();
        }

        // Row click listener:
        RowClickListener onClickListener = listeners.rowClickListener;
        if (onClickListener == null) {
            onClickListener = new RowClickListener();
            listeners.rowClickListener = onClickListener;
        }
                    onClickListener.setToPosition(pos);
        view.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

        // Overflow listener:
        View btn = view.findViewById(R.id.ic_row_btn);
        ButtonListener btnListener = listeners.buttonClickListener;
        if (rowListener == null) {
            btnListener = new ButtonListener(activity);
            listeners.rowClickListener = btnListener;
        }
                    btnListener.setToPosition(pos);
        btnListener.setCollection(collectionId);
        btn.setOnClickListener(btnListener);
    }


    public static class RowClickListeners {
        public RowClickListener rowClickListener;
        public ButtonListener buttonClickListener;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

no single answer above worked for me, but a combination did.

I now set `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on the ListView and `android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` on the ImageButtons in the XML **AND** in Java I also set `descendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS)` on the ListView and `focusable(false), focusableInTouchMode(false), clickable(true)` on the ImageButtons.