# Listview itemclick not work

Tags: android, listview

1. I have a ListView in my ListView show ImageButton.
2. I set focusalble "false" and focusableInTouchMode "false" to ImageButton.
3. I set ListView.OnItemClickListner. When I run my project It's show my ListView.
4. But When I click on Listview It's not working.
5. Then I remove ImageButton in layout and run my project again when i click ListView It' work
6. What wrong ?

Comment: how can we help you without have a code to illustrate your problem...

Comment: set the image button to onclickable false, onfocusable false and also focusable on touch to false.. Also in the adapter set this properties. if u need to implement a click on the image button do it in the adapter class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17803234/4294399

Answer (score 8):

You are not the only sufferer :) **This behavior is often considered as a bug by Android developers**  Have a look at this [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414) of their conversation.

To solve your problem- simply include `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` attribute in your root layout.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using custom `Listview` and in the custom `Listview` row item list if only `Textview` and `Imageview`, you should remove `android:inputType=""`. It cause problem of focusability.

Comment: This works for me I had converted an EDITTEXT to TEXTVIEW hence this was there

Answer (score 1):

Actually nothing is wrong. What you are doing is ok. But i think you forgot one key factor here ImageButton has it's own OnClickListener. So when you embed your ImageButton into the listview row ListView.OnItemClickListner is not working because the click/touch is invoked by ImageButton, it's because of that ListView is not getting your click/touch event.
Checkout this link: [How to fire onListItemClick in Listactivity with buttons in list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821871/how-to-fire-onlistitemclick-in-listactivity-with-buttons-in-list)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using customize list view Item just try to set 
set `focusable` "false" and `focusableInTouchMode` "false" for all view in your `custom_list_view_item.xml` 
Don't worry about your image button if you using click listener for image Button in adapter, It will also work fine. just do `focusable` "false" and `focusableInTouchMode` "false" for all view in your custom_list_view_item.xml

Answer (score 0):

May be you have written onclick listener for the image button in adapter class

**Example :**

```
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });
```

If you set onclick listener for the listItem .It will automatically consume the action input 
so the list item may not be clicked.