# Buttons in listview do not fire onclick event

Tags: android, android-listview

Buttons in `listview` do not fire `onclick` event but if I click the line it does.

I have a listview in a `fragment`. Each row in the listview has 2 `buttons` and a `textview`. Problem is, if I click the `textview` the event is fired but if I click the buttons the event is not fired. I only have the string in my data adapter since I am dealing with **files** and that is the filename. The buttons will be actions on the files.

**Here is the adapter(I don't have a class for the data adapter, do I have to?)**

```
public class fileExplorerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private ArrayList<String> items;

        public fileExplorerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> items) {
                super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
                this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = convertView;
                if (v == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.file_explorer_cell, null);
                }
                String fileName = items.get(position);
                TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtViewFileName);
                tt.setText(fileName);

                return v;
        }
}
```

**here is the setup for the event in the fragment**

```
// ListView Item Click Listener
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Log.d("debug", "in item clicked");

            // ListView Clicked item index
            int itemPosition = position;

            // ListView Clicked item value
            String itemValue = (String) listView
                    .getItemAtPosition(position);

            // Show Alert
            Toast.makeText(
                    rootView.getContext(),
                    "Position :" + itemPosition + "  ListItem : "
                            + itemValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    });
```

Comment: Where is your code for button? It won't fire anything related to button with that code.

Comment: can u show me your xml?

Comment: check[THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208285/listview-itemclick-not-work/20208788#20208788), may be you will get some help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create separate `View.OnClickListener` for your `TextView` and your `Button`s.

If you have a OnItemClickListener, then only the whole item view will respond to click events.

So you should instead do something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.file_explorer_cell, null);
    }
    String fileName = items.get(position);

    // hook up text view
    TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtViewFileName);
    tt.setOnClickListener(textview_onclick);         

    // hook up button one
    Button button1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(button_onclick);

    // hook up button two
    Button button2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button.setOnClickListener(button_onclick2);

    tt.setText(fileName);

    return v;
}
```

and remove the OnItemClickListener.

As a side note, you should set up listeners for individual widgets in each row when convertView is null. I.e. just set them up when they are first created.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any buttons in your code. There is even no eventlistener except for the items (in your case a textview) in the list. From that point of view, your provided code does exactly what you say.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the basics of android programming.

The onItemClick listener responds to the click event of the row of the list, not the button.

Specify the button listener in the getView method first. There are no event listeners for buttons in your code.