# ImageButton in ListView not clickable

Tags: c#, android, listview

I'm currently learning to develop an android app in C#(with xamarin), The problem I have is the ImageButtons in my list are not clickable and I can't seem the find the problem.

The solution I found in other post did not work for me either ([Listview itemclick not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208285/listview-itemclick-not-work))

Here are my codes:

My Fragment:

```
public class MenuFragment : Fragment
{
    private ListView menuListView;
    private List<MenuCategory> menuCategories;

    public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //Create mock menu category
        menuCategories = new List<MenuCategory>();
        menuCategories.Add(new MenuCategory(Resource.Drawable.specialsPromotions, "Promotion and Specials"));
        menuCategories.Add(new MenuCategory(Resource.Drawable.dinner, "Dinner"));

        var view = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.MenuFragment, container, false);

        menuListView = view.FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.menuListView);


        MenuCategoryAdapter adapter = new MenuCategoryAdapter (Activity, menuCategories);
        menuListView.Adapter = adapter;

        menuListView.ItemClick += menuListViewItemClick;

        return view;
    }


    void menuListViewItemClick (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Menu Category selected: " + menuCategories [e.Position].CategoryName);
    }

}
```

My Adapter:

```
public class MenuCategoryAdapter : BaseAdapter<MenuCategory>
{
    List<MenuCategory> menuCategories;
    private Context context;

    public MenuCategoryAdapter (Context context, List<MenuCategory> menuCategories)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.menuCategories = menuCategories;
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get{ return menuCategories.Count; }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override MenuCategory this[int position]
    {
        get{ return menuCategories [position];}

    }

    public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null) 
        {
            row = LayoutInflater.From (context).Inflate (Resource.Layout.MenuCategoryListView, null, false);
        }

        ImageButton button = row.FindViewById<ImageButton> (Resource.Id.menuCategoryName);

        button.SetBackgroundResource (menuCategories [position].BackgroundImage);

        return row;
    }

}
```

My layouts:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/menuListView"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>
```

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/menuCategoryName"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```

Comment: What if you add the attribute `android:clickable="true"` to your item `LinearLayout`?

Comment: you mean by  setting clickable to true in my ImageButton? i tried that and it didn't work...

Comment: No, I mean your LinearLayout, indeed. It could be ignoring clicking, so your `ImageButton` won't receive that click either.

Comment: @joao2fast4u tried adding clickable in my LinearLaouts but that didnt work either .. :(

Comment: Then, add an `onClickListener` to your `ImageButton` in your `MenuCategoryAdapter`  `GetView()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 suggestions:

- Add the `setOnClickListener` in `GetView`. My example is in Java, don't have C#.
- Remove `descendantFocusability` in your layout. This may not be necessary. But if it is set to **blocksDescendants**, then the child of the layout like ImageButton is not clickable, I believe.
- If you want both ImageButton and the parent Listview to be clickable, then try setting `blocksDescendants` to **beforeDescendants** instead (I never had to do this). Google doc @ [descendantFocusability](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#descendantFocusability)

Code snippet for GetView:

```
public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
   ...
   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
         ...
```