# Cannot click listview android with custom adapter

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-listview

im really newbie android.
Now i try to create a simple custom listview with Header section.
But after i run my program, the listview item isn't clickable.
Here is my code :

**MainActivity.java**

```
package io.hidayat.headerlistview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private CustomAdapter mAdapter;
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_header_detail);

        mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
        mAdapter.addSectionHeaderItem("Section #1");
        for (int i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
            mAdapter.addItem("Row Item #" + i);
            if (i % 4 == 0) {
                mAdapter.addSectionHeaderItem("Section #" + i);
            }
        }

        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
package io.hidayat.headerlistview;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;

    private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
    private TreeSet<Integer> sectionHeader = new TreeSet<Integer>();

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void addItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addSectionHeaderItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        sectionHeader.add(mData.size() - 1);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return sectionHeader.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int rowType = getItemViewType(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (rowType) {
            case TYPE_ITEM:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
                holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                break;
            case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.header, parent, false);
                holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
                break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;
    }

}
```

**Header and Row XML is simillar.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#FF000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_header_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="16dip"
        android:paddingBottom="16dip"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:divider="@null"/>   

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm sory, but here the screenshoot of my aplication : [screenshoot](http://s9.postimg.org/bdvxom12n/Screenshot_2015_05_20_10_48_21.png)

Comment: where have you written the listitem click code ? Did you try setting onItemClickListener for the listview ?

Comment: actually i'm not yet add code for on click listener.
i'm just wondering why list item that i touch didn't marked like it clicked.
Because when i follow [this](http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90) tutorial when i touch the item it marked.

Comment: set onitemclicklistener on your list and check [This Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208285/listview-itemclick-not-work/20208788#20208788) to make it proper working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not applied the `OnItemClickListener`. Thats the problem. No worries. You can see the example below to change your code as required.

First implement your `Class` with `OnItemClickListener` like

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener
```

Then attach the `OnItemClickListener` to your `list`

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(YourClassName.this);
```

Then override the `onItemClick` method to implement your functionality at the `position` being clicked.

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Toast.makeText(Test.this, "CLICK: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Please let me know, if you face any trouble. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Shaik, your code is work for an on ClickListener. Thank you so much.
but do you know why the item that i touch didn't marked like i clicked, the color is always same like i never click the item.

Comment: My pleasure. Please accept my answer, if you are satisfied.

Comment: Off course, it done. :)
but please help me why the item that i touch didn't marked like i clicked, the color is always same like i never click the item.

Comment: You can refer to `Esteam's` answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976431/change-background-color-of-selected-item-on-a-listview

Answer (score 1):

invoke the below method on your listview

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: hi dora, thanks for your help, but Shaik give me more detail how to do it. Your answer is also help me.
but i still wondering why the item didn't marked like it clicked, the color is always same like never clicked

Answer (score 1):

The row item must have a param like `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants".` use this for your row item parent .. It works perfectly for a listview that has CustomAdapter..

Comment: hi RajaReddy i already add that param in my XML for row item. Look at my attached code please..

Comment: you have to add onItemClickListener to your list view