# ImageButton click event works, but ListView click event does not

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

### `ListView`:

```xml
<ListView android:id="@+id/list11" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_weight="1" 
          android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"> 
</ListView>
```

### `custome.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_groupname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="asdasd"
        android:textColor="@color/TextColor" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/delete_gp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### `Activity.java`:

```java
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        long itemValue = listView.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
        Log.e("==>", "" + itemValue);
    }

});
```

---

When I click on the `<ImageButton>` it works fine, but when I click on `<ListView>` it does not work.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: My Listview is :- <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/list11"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
                    </ListView>

Comment: show your baseadapter.

Comment: @Go2 try `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` for the root elementin custome.xml

Comment: @Raghunandan does it require if we had kept all child as `android:focusable="false"` .? :-/

Comment: @SilentKiller try it yourself with ImageButton

Comment: @Raghunandan i checked. and it is working fine without it. that's why i asked sir. that do we require to do that too.?

Comment: @SilentKiller yes it works with ImageButton . check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428303/android-cant-click-on-listview-row-with-imagebutton

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks for explanation. i was unaware of this. :)

Comment: @SilentKiller also `android:focusable="false"` will prevent the focus when you click on the same. If you want a listener for ImageButton then when you click it needs to focus. I am not sure if it s the best explanation.

Comment: may be it is or its not. But it clear me. where to use `android:descendantFocusability` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ImageButton` takes focus when you click on list item

Add the below

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to the root element in `custome.xml`

Comment: @Go2 also what does this return  `listView.getItemIdAtPosition(position)`. You need to cast it to the proper type. What is the datatype?

Comment: @Go2 cast it to `long` its better

Answer (score 0):

You will use this code and it will ask to cast the object you just put the casting after it will fine....

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        long itemValue = parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
        Log.e("==>", "" + itemValue);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

add android:clickable="true" in the textview and the imagebutton also