# listview item click event not working in android

Tags: java, android, listview, onclicklistener, listviewitem

1. I have a `ListView`in my `ListView` show `ImageButton`, `ImageView`, `Button`, `TextView`
2. I set `ListView.OnItemClickListner`. When I run my project, it shows my ListView.
3. But when i click on `listview` it's not working
4. what is wrong? and I want button, `ImageButon`,`ImageView` click events should call Activity or dialog ? Help me?

This is the code:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "sdadad",1).show();


    }
});
```

Comment: some of the element in listview row is taking the focus

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428303/android-cant-click-on-listview-row-with-imagebutton

Comment: 1) Why you have a `ListView` inside your `ListView`? You can use `ExpandableListView` for that. -- 2) For your click problem, i guess it's related to `descendantFocusability`.

Answer (score 0):

Add one `tag` in parent layout of your custom layout

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```