# GridView Click is not Working

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am displaying thumbnial in `GridView` using `YouTubeThumbnailView`. It is working fine. When i click item in `GridView` it is clickable.
below is my GridView item Xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_150sdp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
                android:id="@+id/similar_thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_90sdp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/thumbnail_image" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_below="@+id/similar_thumbnail"
                android:id="@+id/similar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Video Title" />
        </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Now there is a need to add a play icon button on YouTubeThumbnialView.
When I added a `ImageButton` on `YouTubeThumbnailView` using `RelaytiveLayout` or `FrameLayout`, `setOnItemClickListner` is not working of `GridView`.
Below is xml of add button on YoutubeThumbnailView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_150sdp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
                android:id="@+id/similar_thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_90sdp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/thumbnail_image" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"/>

            </FrameLayout>
            <TextView
                android:layout_below="@+id/similar_thumbnail"
                android:id="@+id/similar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Video Title" />
        </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Why? How can i add button on `YouTubeThumbnailView` and make `GridView` Clickable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android: cant click on listview row with imagebutton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428303/android-cant-click-on-listview-row-with-imagebutton)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Your link is helpful and its worked