# Switch button in table row not registering click event

Tags: java, android, tablerow

I was having some problem when trying to set the onClick listener of switch on my dynamically generated table row. Here is the code:

```
TableRow row = new TableRow(this.getActivity());
Switch toggleOffOn = new Switch(new ContextThemeWrapper(this.getActivity(), R.style.Switch), null, 0);
boolean toggleValue = Boolean.valueOf(templateDirs.get(i).get(4));
        toggleOffOn.setChecked(toggleValue);
        toggleOffOn.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams(100, android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        toggleOffOn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked) System.out.println("TURE");
                else System.out.println("FALSE");
            }
        });
row.addView(toggleOffOn);
tableEditReminders.addView(row);
```

When I try to click on the switch, nothing happened. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't click on listview row with imagebutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428303/cant-click-on-listview-row-with-imagebutton)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by referring to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428303/cant-click-on-listview-row-with-imagebutton) which is to set these three attributes and it is working now:

```
toggleOffOn.setFocusable(false);
toggleOffOn.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
toggleOffOn.setClickable(true);
```