# Quick Action Dialog/popup with checkbox & button in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-dialog

I'm looking for Quick action dialog which contains 4 Checkbox & 1 is (ok) button.. 
please. Suggest me a good sample regarding this....I'm trying to do this functionality for 3 days.. Went through many code but it not contain check box and button...   Here is the image of what I'm looking for:

[Quick dialog using onclick search view in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351670/quick-dialog-using-onclick-search-view-in-android)

Please show your kind help!Thanks in advance...

Comment: Here is the answer for above question..
Rfer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351670/quick-dialog-using-onclick-search-view-in-android

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PopupWindow` and put any layout you want in it if none of canned quick box implementation fits your needs.

More on PopupWindow in [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html). For tutorials just google for "*android popupwindow tutorial*" (first example [here](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/03/example-of-using-popupwindow.html)).

Comment: Thanks a lot...Its working....But Example-If add 1 checkbox in my layout it will become double in output... here is my code can u check once.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351670/quick-dialog-using-onclick-search-view-in-android  in that QuickAction.java.

Comment: You are using 3rd party code - I do not know it so it is hard to tell what is wrong. Usually, while using PopupWindow you can control anything you want. incl. layout without any problems. You just design your popup's layout as anything else, i.e. in Eclipse Visual Editor