# Indexable Listview in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to get an indexable list in my list view. I referred [this](https://github.com/woozzu/IndexableListView/blob/master/src/com/woozzu/android/widget/IndexScroller.java). But while using the code, I'm facing with an error while using Korean Characters in the StringMatcher class. Can anyone explain me the usage of this class? Is this class required for English Characters as well?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this out , maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560919/android-listview-with-fast-scroll-and-alphabetical-section-index

Comment: Thanks V4Vendetta. This helped me a bit. But on clicking on the alphabets in the index, only a toast message is displayed indicating the alphabet that's been clicked on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some changes to be done to make it work. In order to compile the project and get rid of korean text update the **StringMatcher class**

```
package com.woozzu.android.util;

public class StringMatcher {
    public static boolean match(String value, String keyword) {
        if (value == null || keyword == null)
            return false;
        if (keyword.length() > value.length())
            return false;

        int i = 0, j = 0;
        do {
            int vi = value.charAt(i);
            int kj = keyword.charAt(j);
            if (isKorean(vi) && isInitialSound(kj)) {
            } else {
                if (vi == kj) {
                    i++;
                    j++;
                } else if (j > 0)
                    break;
                else
                    i++;
            }
        } while (i < value.length() && j < keyword.length());

        return (j == keyword.length())? true : false;
    }

    private static boolean isKorean(int i) {
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean isInitialSound(int i) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @AkshatJaiswal superb