# Creating custom android fast scroll overlay

Tags: android, listview, overlay, fastscroll

I have a listview and I want to have a custom fast scroll overlay similar to this one [image]

How can I achieve this? I just need pointing in the right direction.

Comment: You could use this library https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1582 if you're willing to switch to a RecylerView instead of a ListView

Comment: Take a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560919/android-listview-with-fast-scroll-and-alphabetical-section-index