# Button inside ListView not clickable

Tags: android, listview, button, focus, clickable

I want to be able to click on a button inside an item of a ListView. It should have a different effect from clicking the whole item. I realize there are several questions asked on stackoverflow, but none of the suggestions works for me.

The ListView is inside a Fragment.

Layout of the fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".EventFragment" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/event_list"
        android:background="#C0FFFFFF" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout of each list item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="#C0101010">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/event_list_separator"
    style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="separator"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/event_list_element"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:padding="6dip" >

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/event_list_element_icon"
        android:layout_width="26dip"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/event_list_element_firstLine"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dip"
            android:text="item_header"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/event_list_element_secondLine"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Description"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                android:id="@+id/event_list_element_button_1"
                android:layout_width="132dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_button1"
                android:text="Participate"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                />


                <Button
                android:id="@+id/event_list_element_button_2"
                android:layout_width="110dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_button2"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="No thanks"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="14sp" 
                />

                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/event_list_element_additional_text"
                android:layout_width="100dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="sample"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="14sp" /> 
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My list adapter is:

```
public class EventAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Event> {
    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView separator;
        LinearLayout relativeLayout;
        TextView eventHeader;
        TextView eventDescription;
        ImageView blueDot;
        Button button1;
        Button button2;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)     
            _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_list_item, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.relativeLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_list_element);
            viewHolder.blueDot = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_list_element_icon);
            viewHolder.eventHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_list_element_firstLine);
            viewHolder.eventDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_list_element_secondLine);
            viewHolder.button1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_list_element_button1);
            viewHolder.button2 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_list_element_button2);
            viewHolder.separator = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_list_separator);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final Event item = getItem(position);
        if (item != null) {     
            OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Toast.makeText(_context, "boo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };

            viewHolder.button1.setOnClickListener(listener);            
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the two buttons are not clickable. What I tried to far:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.event_list);
listView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
```

I also tried setting on the button:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:clickable="true"
```

I also experimented with android:descendantFocusability.

None of my tries made the buttons clickable.

Comment: Try moving the click listener to the point where you tie the ui elements to the variables.   See if that fixes it, if not then I think your list view is eating the events.

Comment: Typed your question title on Google gave me this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045872/listview-and-buttons-inside-listview

Comment: Thanks, Ardo K. I have seen that on Google. It does not work for me. I was able to add the item click listener, but the button does not react.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert the attribute `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in the Parent Layout declaration of each list item.
The xml should be as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:background="#C0101010">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/event_list_separator"
    style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="separator"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/event_list_element"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:padding="6dip" >

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/event_list_element_icon"
        android:layout_width="26dip"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/event_list_element_firstLine"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dip"
            android:text="item_header"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/event_list_element_secondLine"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Description"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                android:id="@+id/event_list_element_button_1"
                android:layout_width="132dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_button1"
                android:text="Participate"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                />


                <Button
                android:id="@+id/event_list_element_button_2"
                android:layout_width="110dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_button2"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="No thanks"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="14sp" 
                />

                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/event_list_element_additional_text"
                android:layout_width="100dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="sample"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="14sp" /> 
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! I wanted to update the list of events periodically (right now it's a thread running every x milliseconds, later I want to switch that to only update the event list when there is a change). Anyway, the code was (inside my main activity):

```
private BroadcastReceiver _bReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(RECEIVE_EVENT)) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            Event event = (Event) bundle.get("event");
            showEvent(event);
        }
    }
};

private void showEvent(final Event event){
    final Context context = this;

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.event_list);

            EventAdapter adapter = new EventAdapter(context, id.event_list, getEventList());
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);     
        }
    });
}
```

Setting the adapter each time is certainly not the right approach. Once I changed that to only set the adapter once, it worked like suggested using android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

Comment: glad to know that it worked with my suggestion android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" :)