# android, listview with checked box

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-listview

I've read some posts about this matter but still I can't get it to working. I want to have a listview with a checkbox. Here's my `activity_choose_songs.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/songs_to_choose"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sd_cards_playlist"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:divider="#242424"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/songs_to_choose">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's the layout for a specific item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector">

    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/checkedTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:drawableStart="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
        android:textColor="#f3f3f3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's extract from `onCreate()` method in an activity where I want this listview to be displayed:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(),chosenSongsListData,
                R.layout.playlist_checked_item,new String[]{"songTitle"},new int[]{R.id.checkedTextView});

        setListAdapter(adapter);
        ListView lw = getListView();

        lw.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        lw.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        lw.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }
        });
```

Yet, when I'm starting the activity and I' trying to check it, it looks like (the screen is in pressed state):
[image]

What's wrong with my approach?

Comment: Mean, what is wrong, its not checked?

Comment: I suggest using RecyclerView instead, you could set up on click listeners for item and checkbox separately, also check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10529176/2146871

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is you have a `LinearLayout` inside your item view. It cannot propagates its status to the children.

I think you have 2 options.

First one is to remove `LinearLayout`. Your view is not implementing `Checkable` right now. When you remove it `CheckedTextView` should work.

The second option is to use `CheckedLinearLayout` and have your children have this attribute:

```
  android:duplicateParentState="true"`
```

You can find the implementation for `CheckedLinearLayout` online.

Answer (score -1):

You have to do it in your on item click listener, The sample code given below.

```
       lw.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            CheckBox check = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView);

            check.toggle(); //check or un-check the checkbox

            }
        });
```

Comment: Never change the state of the view manually. Only `getView` method should change it. This will not survive scroll and config change where the views are recreated.

Comment: @tasomaniac , Yeah,  Thanks for your comment. I just suggest him because he mentioned "unable to check the check box by clicking the list item" ,And i thought this is the simplest way to do that. I didn't think about retain the state :) .