# how to get id in different layout

Tags: android, android-layout

i have `id "@+id/call"` in `single_item.xml` when i use `findVewById` it (the layout `setcontextview(R.layout.main)`)   .the app crash .how to fix the error

Comment: please show us the exact single_item.xml, the lines where you use setContextView(..) and findViewById(..) and please the logcat of the exception. Than we can provide you a lot quicker with the help you need. With the current information we have no idea where to look or how to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to find a View (R.id.call) that is declared in R.layout.single_item in the layour R.layout.main, so I guess it is throwing a Null Pointer Exception.

You should either declare your "@+id/call" element in your main.xml file, or set the context view to R.layout.single_item

Comment: here the class CustomSqlCursorAdapter

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
    />

Comment: Can you please update your first post with the code? It is really hard to read code without as there is no indentation nor formatting in the comments, plus your "CustomSqlCursorAdapter" class is missing.

Answer (score 51):

If you want to access a view in another layout (not the active layout), then you can inflate the layout you want to use and access it that way.

Example:

```
View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.other_layout, null);
TextView text = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
text.setText("Hello!");
```

More information about inflating layouts can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html).

Comment: i tried  but it dont work correctly  this is the the button in single_item.xml   <Button
        android:text="call"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/call"
        android:clickable="true"
    />  this is some code in class i want to get button  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

Comment: View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.single_item, null);
      Button call = (Button) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.call);
           call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       
           
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     //TODO Auto-generated method stub
     call();
    }                
       });

Comment: i want to use this get the id buton to make a call because the class CustomSqlCursorAdapter extends implements implecursoradapter  i can't use this to do activity so i want to get this from managecontact

Comment: when i click the button nothing happen :(

Comment: So these are buttons inside list items?

Comment: If you are dealing with items inside a ListView, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322390/android-row-becomes-unclickable-with-button/2323085#2323085.

Comment: it 's also my prbolem .more inportantly, i want to make a call

Comment: u can see the example http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.com/2010/03/clicking-buttons-in-listview-row.html and give me some solution

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to fetch `id` from a view is:

```
String id = getResources().getResourceEntryName(view.getId());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the id in the fragment use the following method.
replace the return statement with view like this.

```
 View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_left, container, false);
 img=view.findViewById(R.id.image);
 return view;
```

call all the methods before you return the view.

Answer (score -2):

```
View parent = (View)view.getParent();
??? = (???)parent.findViewById(R.id.call);
```

try this. hope it help