# Getting nullpointerexception despite assinging a value to it

Tags: java, android

I am creating a basic android app. I am creating a `TextView` object called `mathexpresionTV` and assigning to the value of the id of the textview I want it to reference to.

```
TextView mathExpressionTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mathexpressiontextview);
```

I also have a button in which if the user presses it, it displays 1 on the textview.

```
 Button oneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)
    oneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               mathExpressionTV.append("0");
            }
        });
```

I am will be using the `mathExpressionTV` through the class hence I have delcared it as a global variable and not on my `onCreate();` method but the `oneButton` is declared in my `onCreate();`.

This is the error output: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: In which function are you executing this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare it as a global, but you need to cast as a  `TextView` in `onCreate`. You can't use `findViewById` outside of a method in an activity

```
TextView mathExpressionTV;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourActivity);

    mathExpressionTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mathexpressiontextview);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Oh okay, Thanks that fixed it. Do you know if we can reference other View objects if its not in the layout from the current avctivity? E.g. if there was a textview in layout A.xml and my current activity, C.java sets the content as B.xml, would be able to get the reference of the rextview from A.xml

Comment: That's not typically what you should be trying to do. It can be done if you inflate the other layout, take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211189/how-to-get-id-in-different-layout

Comment: So do you recommened inflating other layouts?

Comment: It really depends, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? It may be best to ask a new question entirely

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options:

1. Use `findViewById` in the `onCreate` method
2. Create a global variable for the `textView` and assign it in the `onCreate` method
3. Pass the activity object, or get the activity object and use it like: `activity.findViewById`