# ListView with multiple buttons, list item can't be clicked

Tags: android, listview, clickable

I have a list with two buttons in it. When I want to click a list item it doesn't work, but my button is still clickable.
**How I can make all buttons include the entire list item to be clickable?**

List item:

```
<TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:mode="twoLine">
       
              <Button
                    android:id="@+id/erase"
                    android:layout_width="40dip"
                    android:layout_height="40dip"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
              <ImageButton android:id="@+id/soundf"
                    android:layout_width="40dip"
                    android:layout_height="40dip"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/> 
              <TextView android:id="@+id/texxt1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#CC0"/>
</TwoLineListItem>
```

Layout containing the ListView:

```
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button android:id="@+id/left" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="English to Indonesia"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:background="@drawable/chbutt" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/right" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Indonesia to English"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:background="@drawable/chbutt" />
    </LinearLayout>
    
    <ListView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/history"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:isScrollContainer="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you provide you xml where you have defined listview

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322390/android-row-becomes-unclickable-with-button/2323085#2323085

Comment: hi @Deepak, you can see it now

Answer (score 29):

For **Buttons**, **Checkboxs** and **ImageViews**:

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Now both (buttons and rows) of ListView are clickable.

For **ImageButtons**, you have to set focusable while running, because the constructor of ImageButtons sets it to true.
I recommend you using a ImageView instead of a ImageButton.

Comment: I've been agonizing over this issue for some time.  Thank you very much sir.

Comment: Thanks, this topic used to give me a couple of headaches! Its a little bit trick.

Comment: how will you identify whether the click is from listitem or the button??

Comment: you'd be called on the listener for the list or the button respectively

Comment: Thanks for a hint regarding the constructor of ImageButtons!

Comment: More details about the reason, thanks! Please give some references.

Comment: Use **ImageView** works for me without handle the _focus_ property in some way.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout  android:id="@+id/rel1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button
        android:id="@+id/erase"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:background="@drawable/closebtn"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    />
   <ImageButton android:id="@+id/soundf"
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/erase"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/erase"
        android:background="@drawable/soundinv"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        /> 
   <TextView android:id="@+id/texxt1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/erase"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/erase"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#CC0"
   />

   <TextView android:id="@+id/texxt2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/texxt1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/texxt1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
   />
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

now you can also given click event to relative layout.

Comment: hey, check my xml again it's TwoLineListItem, and I found nothing wrong with it

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your Java code: `holder.yourButton.setFocusable(false);`
I am using my own cursorAdapter so I am putting the line of code at the end of `bindView`
this should do it.