# Adding a button to the ExpandableListView Group item

Tags: android, expandablelistview, custom-view

I am customizing an ExapndableListView,, I am trying to add a Button to the Group Item,,

The problem is that if the button is focussable  the group does't expand on click. I want the group to expand normally and the button to be clicked normally.

Anybody knows how I could accomplish that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the button not focusable. button.[setFocusable(false)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setFocusable%28boolean%29)

This should to the job.

Comment: Check this question --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322390/android-row-becomes-unclickable-with-button/2323085#2323085