# Android listview with buttons

Tags: android

I have a listview with custom listitem. I have bunch of textviews in Relative layout. And when I click on listitem it goes to different screen. Now I have added 3 buttons and toggle button to list item and I CAN NOT CLICK THE LIST ITEM. What am I missing :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set focusable property of all the buttons  to false and so that  you can click on list and also touch event for all buttons will work

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks the row, the ListView will look for a widget implementing the Checkable interface. The RelativeLayout does not. An easy way to do that is simply to create your own CheckableRelativeLayout class. See http://www.marvinlabs.com/2010/10/custom-listview-ability-check-items/ for a full tutorial with code.

Also, the buttons and other items in your row layout should not be focusable. You can see other SO questions: [Android Row becomes Unclickable with Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322390/android-row-becomes-unclickable-with-button/2323085#2323085)