# Android ExpandableListView Parent with Button

Tags: android, button, expandablelistview

I am trying to achieve something like this.
The Expandable List consists of the names of certain categories and when a parent is clicked, it shows the list of all the children in that category.
Now, suppose I want dynamically add a child to any category ?
How do I do that ?
Do I keep a button with every parent  in the list clicking on which would add a new child under it ?

But looking around in different forums, I came to realize that it is not really easy to set a button click handler inside every parent. But if that is the only way, can anyone give me some sample code please ?

I found this thread but wasn't able to implement it in my code.
[Android Row becomes Unclickable with Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322390/android-row-becomes-unclickable-with-button/2323085#2323085)

Comment: How are you populating the list?  From a cursor?  With arrays?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding a button to the group view shouldn't be that difficult.

I believe the below should work (although I don't have a project using an array backed ExpandableListView to test on).

I don't know your group row layout, so I'll make one up here for reference purposes.

**group_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="Add"
        android:textSize="12dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your `getGroupView` method from your adapter:

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    if (convertView == null) {
        View convertView = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.group_layout, null);
        Button addButton = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.addButton);

        addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // your code to add to the child list
            }
        });
    }        
    TextView textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString()); 
    return convertView; 
}
```